# Генерация sitemap.xml в WordPress без плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Как генерировать `sitemap.xml` в WordPress без плагина? Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться. Можно ли сделать автоматическую отправку обновленного файла в Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начать надо с перехвата имени страницы sitemap и генерации карты на лету. В приведенном ниже коде показано, как это сделать. Код рабочий, сгенерированные им файлы проходят проверку в Google Search Console, несмотря на то, что `.xml` файлы карты в браузере выглядят ужасно. Но на них можно повесить стили `.xsl`, если хочется внешней красоты.

Первая часть кода генерирует `/sitemap.xml`, содержащую ссылки на 3 карты: постов, страниц и категорий.

Генератор карты постов запускает цикл по всем существующим постам и строит карту. Время в тегах `<lastmod>` в примере взято с потолка, его надо вытаскивать из базы. То же самое относится и к изображениям поста. Впрочем, Яндекс теги `<image:image>` не понимает, зато с ними может работать Google.

```
function sitemap() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $scheme = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
    if ($scheme) $scheme = 'https';
        else $scheme = 'http';
    if ($path == '/sitemap.xml') {
        ?>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
                <sitemap>
                    <loc><?php echo site_url('/post-sitemap.xml', $scheme); ?></loc>
                    <lastmod>2016-04-28T10:29:38+03:00</lastmod>
                </sitemap>
                <sitemap>
                    <loc><?php echo site_url('/page-sitemap.xml', $scheme); ?></loc>
                    <lastmod>2017-01-23T14:13:43+02:00</lastmod>
                </sitemap>
                <sitemap>
                    <loc><?php echo site_url('/category-sitemap.xml', $scheme); ?></loc>
                    <lastmod>2016-04-28T10:25:13+03:00</lastmod>
                </sitemap>
            </sitemapindex>
        <!-- XML Sitemap generated by own plugin -->
        <?php
        die();
    }

    if ($path == '/post-sitemap.xml') {
        ?>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
            <url>
                <loc><?php echo site_url('', $scheme); ?></loc>
                <lastmod>2016-04-28T10:29:38+03:00</lastmod>
            </url>
            <?php
                $args = array (
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type' => 'post');
                $posts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
                    ?>
                    <url>
                        <loc><?php echo $url; ?></loc>
                        <lastmod>2016-04-28T10:25:13+03:00</lastmod>
                        <image:image>
                            <image:loc>https://kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/6-sites-page-speed.jpg</image:loc>
                            <image:title><![CDATA[6-sites-page-speed]]></image:title>
                        </image:image>
                    </url>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </urlset>
        <!-- XML Sitemap generated by own plugin -->
        <?php
        die();
    }
}
```