# Непростая выборка из MySQL WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Здравствуйте! В базе есть категории `wp_terms`. Связи категорий(где указывается кто родитель категории находятся в таблице `wp_terms_taxonomy`. Так вот мне нужно из таблицы `wp_terms` достать ссылки категорий `slug` родителя и дочернего элемента одним запросом.

```
SELECT `slug` FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id` in (SELECT `term_taxonomy_id` FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'product_cat')
```

этим запросом я вытягиваю ссылки всех категорий независимо от дочернего или родительского.

```
SELECT `slug` FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id` in (SELECT `parent` FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'product_cat')
```

этим запросом ссылки родителей. суть в том, что нужно формировать ссылку для составления карты сайта(sitemap) и нужно формировать ссылку типа http://siteurl/parentslug/term_taxonomy_slug/ надеюсь я понятно расписал. в общем нужно объединить два запроса в один чтобы выводило два значения `slug` `parent`'a и `slug` `wp_term_taxonomy`
`slug` - ссылка на категорию(таблица `wp_terms`);
`parent` - ид родительской категории (таблица `wp_terms_taxonomy`);
`term_taxonomy_id` - ид категории (таблица `wp_terms_taxonomy`)

Comment: Не нужно лазить в базу, если нет стойкого желания поломать сайт и наплодить дыр! Лучше расскажи что хочешь (забыв слова "sql", "база", "php" и тд) и найдутся правильные решения.

Comment: Не нужны все эти сложные выборки. Общая идея создания sitemap.xml без плагинов изложена в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619945/220220

Comment: @SeVlad, интересно, много ты сайтов выборками поломал?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, условие задания построить сайту исходя из базы...

Comment: А у меня в том ответе из чего sitemap строится, из воздуха? Из той же базы, само собой.

Comment: @АнтонБурак я, в отличии от тебя, знаю про АПИ ВП и как вообще работать с движком. Поэтому ничего не ломаю.  Если тебя это интересовало а не как как грамотно решить задачу.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, из какой базы у тебя там строиться? если ты парсишь урл сайта. нет ни коннекта к базе, ни запросов, ничего, видать база твоя реально из воздуха

Comment: @SeVlad, условие задания построить карту сайта исходя из базы. Да и выборками сломать сайт... ну я хз, как ты себе это представляешь?

Comment: @АнтонБурак у тебя база есть, есть коннекты и запросы - а у меня нет. Наверное, у меня и сайта-то нет, в моем примере. И WordPress нет, и цикла foreach по постам нет  - один воздух. Я даже не знаю, как это комментировать. Ты не читаешь или не можешь понять, что тебе пишут. Ну что же, продолжай доставать правой ногой левое ухо. Удачи.

Comment: @АнтонБурак и еще скачай плагин Yoast SEO (более миллиона установок) и поинтересуйся, как он строит sitemap. А потом сравни с моим примером.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, пересмотрел код, мы друг друга не поняли. У меня задача заключалась в том, чтобы брать из базы именно выборками. Дабы продемонстрировать свои знания не только в PHP и знании cms, но и в MySQL. Я задал конкретный вопрос здесь, как слепить из двух запросов один. Вы же начали вникать глубже в суть задачи.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, если кого-то обидел, извиняюсь. увидев строку parse_url я по ошибке решил, что она будет парсить хтмл сайта и оттуда выдирать все необходимое(т.к. раньше натыкался на подобные примеры по построению карты сайта). пересмотрев код и вникнув из вашего примера, понял, что ошибся. прошу прощения. ваш пример подошел бы, не будь моя задача уникальна(использование запросов для построения карты)

Comment: Для ВП опасны домохозяйки, копипастящие код "из интеретов". Но куда более опаснее грамотные (без сарказма) пхп-шники, которые не знают и не желают узнавать ВП. На сёрче я недавно [аналогию показывал](https://searchengines.guru/showpost.php?p=15188217&postcount=28).  @АнтонБурак я вполне серьёзно - если есть желание сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО, надёжно и БЕЗОПАСНО - забудь о базе как об отдельной сущности. Не лазь в неё (можно только в очень не многих случаях и/или когда очень хорошо знаешь ВП) Нужно использовать АПИ ВП.

Comment: @SeVlad, странный ты) я уже давно все сделал без апи, все хорошо. да и в апи вп входит класс впдб... не спроста ведь... а по вашим словам его нужно бояться и упоси господь не трогать

Comment: @АнтонБурак wpdb - это для тек кто очень хорошо понимает что это и зачем. "Последняя миля" для тех, кто хорошо знает ВП. Для решения "хитрых" задач. А в АПИ так же входит и WP_Query и его обёртки (get_posts напр). Без АПИ ничего не сделать. Не сделать правильно и безопасно с см.