# Не работает плагин Google Sitemap XML

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Поставил плагин Google Sitemap XML (google sitemap generator). Он переименовал файлы sitemap.xml и sitemap.xml.gz в sitemap.backup.xml  sitemap.backup.xml.gz сщщтветственно, но данные в них не заносит. Вчем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что плагины такого рода (например, Yoast SEO тоже) создают файл sitemap.xml динамически, во время обращения к такому файлу. Поэтому никакого физического файла sitemap.xml в папках вы не найдете.

Как примерно работает создание sitemap.xml "на лету", я показывал в своем ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619945/220220.