# Динамическая генерация sitemap.xml, в зависимости от домена

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache, sitemap

Вопрос состоит в чём: есть сайт на wordpress, есть убер-сложный самописный плагин, который позволяет на платформе одного сайта (один экземпляр всех файлов) раздавать разные web-страницы, в зависимости от url, по которому пришёл пользователь.

В общем, со стороны пользователя сайтов много, со стороны программиста - один, просто в виде множества страниц. 
При выводе на прод потребовалось добавить sitemap.xml, однако тут возникла конкретная проблема: sitemap должен содержать абсолютные ссылки, а физически то файл всего один:

```
 <url>
    <loc>https://ТУТ ДОМЕН САЙТА/o-proekte</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-07-30T12:06:48+00:00</lastmod>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

И как заставить сервер при отображении файла подкидывать в него нужный хост - мне не известно... Заранее прошу не кидаться тапками за такое корявое решение - оно было спущено сверху, ввиду обратной совместимости с похожей старой системой и её бд.

Собственно, сабж: Как можно заставить сервак подкидывать строки в статический файл при его выдаче, или как заставить его по адресу sitename.ru/sitemap.xml отдавать не физический файл, а, скажем, php страницу, которая будет маскироваться под xml?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619239/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-sitemap-xml-%d0%b2-wordpress-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0/619945#619945

Comment: *Как раздавать статический файл, изменяя его содержимое?* — очевидно, никак. статический файл — это тот, содержимое, которого не меняется. если содержимое меняется в зависимости от запроса, то это не статический файл, а динамический. просто по определению.